# How to parse the Data to get the time Stamp sorted along with Error code

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to grep out a particular string "Server-OUT" from one of the my log file and counting the string that it was appeared the number of times on the file, and if it gets greater than 18 in number then just pop up a mail to me and thats working.

```
#!/bin/bash
ERRCOUNT=$(grep SERVER-OUT /licenses/CapSync30/license_logs/770 |tail -100 | wc -l)
HOSTN="`/bin/hostname`"
if [ "$ERRCOUNT" -ge 18 ]
then
echo "SERVER-OUT Error Count is $ERRCOUNT on $HOSTN" | mailx -s "Urgent !!! Licence Admin Please Investigate the Server $HOSTN for any Issues" karn@dence.com
fi
```

Now, as the log file has the format as below, where i want to cut down the First and Second Column, where i First column has the time and i Want that to be parse precisely as "13:53" , If this "Server-out" appeared between 13:53 repeatedly more than 10 times then send me a mail with number of count including the data.

> 13:53:21 (meta) SERVER-OUT: Failed to send the message(86)

Below what i'm trying to filter the first & second column along with time stamp(hours:minute) with SERVER-OUT message too, but just screwed myself to get that revolving into my mind as of now..

```
$ awk '/SERVER-OUT/ {print $1, $3}' /licenses/CapSync30/license_logs/770
13:53:21 SERVER-OUT:
13:54:06 SERVER-OUT:

$ awk '/SERVER-OUT/ {print $1, $3}' /licenses/CapSync30/license_logs/770 | cut -d: -f1,2 | tail -2
13:53
13:54
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not clear what you're trying to do, but perhaps will give you ideas

```
$ echo "13:53:21 (meta) SERVER-OUT: Failed to send the message(86)" | 
  awk '/SERVER-OUT/{split($1,t,":"); print t[1]":"t[2],$3}'

13:53 SERVER-OUT:
```

or

```
$ ... |  awk '/SERVER-OUT/{print substr($1,1,5),$3}'

13:53 SERVER-OUT:
```

set the counter on the extracted values, using the second alternative...

```
$ ... |  awk '/SERVER-OUT/{counter[substr($1,1,5),$3]++} 
              END         {for(k in counter) if(counter[k]>10) exit 1}'
```

check the exit status and send the notification...

Comment: @karafa , i want if the "13:53 SERVER-OUT:"  <-- gets repeated more than 10 times then send an email to  karn@dence.com.

Comment: @Karn So what you *really* want is: send mail if there are more than 10 SERVER-OUTs *in one minute*, right? Why don't you say so :-)

Comment: @Jens  that's really I want. I got it .